# How can i see the Next item in the list

Tags: java

How can i see the Next item in the list ? its always null when i use this code

```
if (recno!=0){
System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\t   Next Record");
System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t    Employee Number: "+EmpNo[1]);
System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Employee Number: "+EmpName[1]);
System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Salary: : "+Salary[1]);
System.out.print("\n\n\t\t  Do you want to see the next record ? [press n]");
next = reader.readLine();

if(next!="y"){
    recno++;

    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t    Employee Number: "+EmpNo[recno]);
    System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Employee Name: "+EmpName[recno]);
    System.out.print("\n\t\t\t    Salary: "+Salary[recno]);
}
}
else{
    System.out.print("\n\n\t\t\t\tRecord Not Found!");
}
```

Comment: post the whole code/runnable code

Comment: I can't see any `List` here.

Comment: Fie on this: `next!="y"`

Comment: The idea to let the user press "n" as the reply to an question "Do you want to see the next record" is psychologically interesting. How many will think that "n" means "next"? How many will opt for "n" == "no"?

Answer (score 1):

It sure would help to use equals here:

```
if(! "y".equals(next) ){
```